# React styling - Overflow issues - Expo & Electron single workflow

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flatlist, react-component

I'm struggling with styling an element within react and being a complete newbie to the language would love some help from this awesome community. I'm having issues with scrollable content areas and overflows, which are dynamic. In the react version (seen below) the container has been expanded which has caused the window to have a scroll bar. In the html version below you can see how I intended the UI to look with a scrolling section to the left.

Rather than clutter this post with loads of code (there is a lot of code), the source files for the interface can be found at https://gitlab.com/tgtmedialtd/smartcloud/core/tree/master/package/interface

and the source files for the prototype version can be found at https://gitlab.com/tgtmedialtd/smartcloud/core/tree/master/package/desktop

If you wish to run either of them, simply do `yarn install && yarn start` after cloning the files

HTML + CSS || Prototype Version

[image: Prototype Version]

React Native || Build Version

[image: Build Version]

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: `maxHeight: 50% == 50%screenHeight`not `50%windowHeight` as I was expecting. Solved using `react.Dimensions` & Listeners for remote resize

Ok, so Even though not many people have seen this post, and not may probably ever will, I have discovered my issue.

So quick explanation of the workflow I am using:

Using React-Native I am rending content dynamically, for mobile, website and desktop applications. This is managed through using Expo and Electron. More on this can be found here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/guides/using-electron/

***Research / Discovery***

So I spent a long while playing with classes, styles and other rending methods until I eventually landed on the style setting `maxHeight`. Setting this to `50%` I was expecting the element to be 50% of the window. However, this was not the case.

[image: maxHeight: 50%]

This quickly leads to the realisation that react was choosing to find the screen height not the window height...

***Now to the solution.***

To solve, was not as easy as I originally thought due to the workflow I am using, there are a few hurdles which I was already aware of when it comes to using `electron/remote`. Luckily this is solved by a simple extra file named `*.electron.tsx`. So here is how I ended up doing this.

```js
//global.tsx - Lines commented out are included in global.electron.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import * as styles from '../assets/styles/main'
import { Example } from './chat/example'
import { ChannelSelect } from './channels/select'
import { ChannelOptions } from './channels/options'

// let remote, win
// try { remote = require('electron').remote }catch(_){}
// try { win = remote.getCurrentWindow() }catch(_){}

export class Container extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showMenu: false,
    style: {},
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width
  }

  handler = (dims:any) => this.setState(dims);
  // logger = () => {
  //   const winHeight = win.getSize()[1];
  //   this.setState({height: winHeight});
  // };


  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleToggleClick = this.handleToggleClick.bind(this);
    this.TopBar = this.TopBar.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Dimensions.addEventListener("change", this.handler);
    // win.on("will-resize", this.logger)
    if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
      this.setState({
        style: {position: 'absolute', zIndex: 2, left: 0, top: 0, borderRightWidth: 3, borderColor: styles.colours.b5}
      })
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Dimensions.removeEventListener("change", this.handler);
  }

  async handleToggleClick (){
    if (this.state.showMenu) {
      this.setState({showMenu: false})
    } else {
      this.setState({showMenu: true })
    }
  }

  TopBar (props) {
    return (
      <View key="ChannelContentTopBar" style={styles.global.topBar} >
      {
        Platform.OS!=='web' ? ([
          <View onTouchEnd={this.handleToggleClick} style={{flex: 1, marginLeft: 10, alignContent: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/img/icon.png')} style={{height:50, width:50}}/>
          </View>,
          <View style={{flex: 3, alignContent: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/img/logo_sub.png')} style={{height:30, width: 150, alignSelf: 'center'}}/>
          </View>,
          <View style={{flex: 1, alignContent: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}} />
        ]) : null
      }
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const {height, width} = this.state;
    // const {height, width} = this.state;
    // let containHeight: number
    // if (Platform.OS=='web') {containHeight = height-20}else{containHeight = height}
    return (
      <View key="container" style={[styles.global.container, {maxHeight: height, maxWidth: width}]}>
       { this.state.showMenu || Platform.OS=='web' ?  ( [
         <View key="selectContainer" style={[styles.channels.Container, this.state.style]}>
            <ChannelSelect />
            <ChannelOptions />
        </View>
      ]) : null }
      {
        this.state.showMenu && Platform.OS!=='web' ? (
          <View key="mainContent" style={styles.global.mainContent} onTouchEnd={this.handleToggleClick}>
            <this.TopBar />
            <Example />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <View key="mainContent" style={styles.global.mainContent}>
            <this.TopBar />
            <Example />
          </View>
        )
      }
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

[image: Working Version]

I am sure there is a better, and neater way of doing this, but for now, this works and does what I need it to do. If I improve this code I will update the scripts and leave a note. Now I can finally start fixing some styling issues xD

Edit one: to neaten up my code, I move this all into my global container to define the size of the window once.